# ASP.NET 4.0 and VS2008?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-4.0

Will VS2008 be able to develop ASP.NET 4.0 applications when it is released?

I would hate to have to go buy VS2010 just for a couple of features I'm looking forward two like Dynamic Data and session profiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can develop .NET applications without Visual Studio at all, so you could use Visual Studio 2008 as a helpful tool in that regard but looking at the previous Visual Studio releases, it's very unlikely that you'll get first class support for .NET 4.0 features. Personally, I think the short answer to your question is "No."

By the way, ASP.NET Dynamic Data is already available in .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and VS2008 supports it.

Comment: I was mentioning ASP.NET Dynamic Data 4.0

The currently version (1.0) can't hold a candle to 4.0, I've seen the previews.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will require Visual Studio 2010.

It may in theory be possible to do some hacks with MSBuild like there was for .NET 1.1 from VS2005 but it'll be completely unsupported, your intellisense wont work right, etc.

You don't need to buy VS2010, you can just download the free Express versions, likw with previous releases.